# 9 V Electric Lighter

Tags: resistance, heat

I wanted to build an electric lighter with a 9 V battery. I ordered 32 Gauge Nichrome Wire, a push switch and lots of 9 V batteries.

For testing, I attached aligator clips to the battery and to the wire. The nichrome wire only got a little bit warm, not hot.

I tested the voltage of the battery with a multimeter and it was arround 0.9 volts. The wire was around 1cm long.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: 9Volt batteries don't contain a lot of energy.  They cannot provide 9Volts into a short circuit (which nichrome wire is until it gets really hot) for very long - and certainly not long enough to get the wire red hot.  I find 32 gauge nichrome wire available with a resistance of about 10 Ohms per 30cm.  So, your 1 cm long piece of wire had a resistance of .3Ohms.  At 9 Volts that'd be close to 30 Amperes.  A 9Volt battery is rated for 110 mA hours.  At 30 A, the battery is dead in a little over 10 seconds.

Comment: *Would be* dead, since there's no way you're pulling 30A from a 9V battery.

Comment: Hmm. 0.3 Ohms and a car battery may make a very good starting point for an estes rocket engine igniter, though. I think the standard squib is about 0.66 Ohms and has an all-fire spec of 300 mJ in 50 ms, from a nice discussion I had with an Estes engineer, years back.

Comment: you should have used Tungsten wire instead because it has about 10x lower hot resistance, like toasters use...

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams A colleague measured a fair bit more than that from a 9V NiCd battery- right before it exploded.

Comment: If you need an emergency lighter, you can ignite fine steel wool with a 9 V battery.

Comment: Clearly you didn't even glance at the datasheet for the battery!

Answer (score 2):

Every real-world source of electrical power has a non-zero internal resistance:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmY6o6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For typical 9V alkaline batteries, an internal resistance of about 2 Ω is often assumed.

Now, as @JRE said, your 1 cm of (cold) Nichrome wire should have a resistance of ca 0.3 Ω.

Hence, the internal and the load resistance form a voltage divider, with the Voltage across the load (==heating) resistance being

$$
\begin{align}
U_\text{load}&= U_0 \cdot \frac{R_\text{load}}{R_\text{i} + R_\text{load}}\\
&= 9 \text{ V} \cdot \frac{0.3}{2.3}\\
&\approx 1.17 \text{ V}\,\text{.}
\end{align}
$$

Now, knowing that the power lost is

$$
\begin{align}
P_\text{load}&= U_\text{load} \cdot I_\text{load}\\
&= U_\text{load} \cdot \frac{U_\text{load}}{R_\text{load}}\\
&=\frac{U_\text{load}^2}{R_\text{load}}\\
&\approx\frac{{1.15 \text{ V}}^2}{0.3\,\Omega}\\
&\approx 4.4 \text{ W}\,\text{,}
\end{align}
$$

which isn't very much, but should still feel relatively warm. My guess is that the contact you've made between wire and battery terminals is pretty bad and you're incurring another couple of Ohms resistance here, making the power matching even worse.